# Exporting SharePoint data to external PHP script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

My client has his intranet website running as a SharePoint 2010 site, consisting of about 40 lists making the different categories of news.

What would be the easiest way for me to fetch this data (including the contents html-formatting) to an external solution that's written in PHP?

The fetching/exporting must happen automatically. Either every time changes are made to one of the lists, or at a timed interval (i.e. every hour).

I was looking into the built-in RSS-feed option of SharePoint 2010. Will the RSS-fields contain the HTML-formatting as well? Or is there a smarter way to handle this export?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for list data, you can fire off a `curl` request to one of SharePoint's list REST services, and parse the results. Should be pretty simple. There's also a full set of SOAP web services, but those have been deprecated in 2013, so I'd argue that developing a solution using REST is likely more future proof. You could start [here](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/01/21/introduction-to-querying-lists-with-rest-and-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) for a simple introduction to REST. Once you understand the concept and what comes back just open a `curl` connection in PHP and parse the dataset for the element(s) you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is mostly asking about how to do things in PHP which I wonder if anyone here will going to help you with, you might would like to try [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for that.

However you can get data from SharePoint using web services, here's few examples,

[Reading a SharePoint list with PHP (updated)](http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-php/)

[web-service to get sharepoint data gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495473/web-service-to-get-sharepoint-data-gives-error)

[PHP SharePoint Lists API](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API)

You should look for something in PHP which will fetch data hourly.